# How can i create an instance of multi-layer perceptron network to use in bagging classifier?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, data-mining

i am trying to create an instance of multi-layer perceptron network to use in bagging classifier. But i don't understand how to fix them.

Here is my code:

```
My task is:

1-To apply bagging classifier (with or without replacement) with eight base classifiers created at the previous step.


It would be really great if you show me how can i implement this to my algorithm. I did my search but i couldn't find a way to do that
```

Comment: Please edit your question to focus on 1 problem only. If you have many, please open 1 question per 1 problem, This way you'll help others to find answers easier.

Answer (score 1):

To train your `BaggingClassifier`:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler  
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier 
from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix

#Load the digits data:

X,y = load_digits(return_X_y=True)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)
# Feature scaling
scaler = StandardScaler()  
scaler.fit(X_train)
X_train = scaler.transform(X_train)  
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)
# Finally for the MLP- Multilayer Perceptron
mlp = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(16, 8, 4, 2), max_iter=1001)

clf = BaggingClassifier(mlp, n_estimators=8)
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

To analyze your output you may try:

```
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred, labels=clf.classes_)
print(cm)
```

To see num of correctly predicted instances per class:

```
print(cm[np.eye(len(clf.classes_)).astype("bool")])
```

To see percentage of correctly predicted instances per class:

```
cm[np.eye(len(clf.classes_)).astype("bool")]/cm.sum(1)
```

To see total accuracy of your algo:

```
(y_pred==y_test).mean()
```

**EDIT**

To access predictions on a per base estimator basis, i.e. your mlps, you can do:

```
estimators = clf.estimators_
# print(len(estimators), type(estimators[0]))
preds = []
for base_estimator in estimators:
    preds.append(base_estimator.predict(X_test))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that beautiful answer. The thing is, i need to find num of correctly predicted instances per each classifiers. How can i edit my code to divide it into 8 classifiers? Is my code so far correct for that task???

Comment: `BaggingClassifier(mlp)` gives you average over 10 mlp (see docs). To adjust for your assignment change `n_estimators`. To access base_estimators you may do `clf._estimators`

Comment: thank you for your answer, i changed `BaggingClassifier(mlp)` as `BaggingClassifier(mlp, n_estimators=8)` .After that how can i calculate number of correctly classified test instance for each base classifier? I am sorry but i looked it up but i don't understand clf._estimators part.

Comment: Please see the **EDIT**

Comment: thank you, i used the code and it creates a list of predictions on a per base estimator basis i calculated the number of the digits in the results. But all of instances give the same instance count. In my researches it says, each base estimater should give the different instance count. i.e. (289 out of 540 instances) How can i fix this?

Comment: All estimators produce X_test.shape[0] number of predictions. How they can be different if they predict on the same data?

Comment: Yes, you are right. But i want to measure the accuracy of the predictions. I want to find the correct number of instances that are correctly predicted per base estimator basis. I hope i expressed myself correctly. Thanks a lot for helping me, i learned so much. Output should be like `289 out of 540 instances are correctly classified by learner #1` and 7 other outputs like that.

Comment: I showed you how to do that for clf. You can copy paste that for the base estimators?

Comment: I tried using `print(cm[np.eye(len(clf.estimators_)).astype("bool")])` but it gives the error (IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 10 but corresponding boolean dimension is 8) Is that the way of doing it?